# Is PostgreSQL for storing images for a low traffic project reasonable?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I've read several answers here about why binaries/images in SQL can be a bad idea (e.g. increases backup times, can make queries slow). The project we have is:

- We have to store about 5000 images online, max 1MB each so about 5GB of storage total along with a little metadata for each image. It's not likely to grow more complex in the future.
- We'll have a CMS that lets you modify/upload photos. It's likely only one person at a time will be using this.
- We have an app that runs on a single computer that will keep its own copy of all the photos for speed of display (i.e. when a photo is added by the CMS, we'll have some method of syncing this image to the app). For the sake of an example, imagine this app is a constantly running slideshow.

The plan is to use something like AWS or Heroku to host an SQL database with automated backups and metadata+images will be stored in the database.

The big pros of this over using e.g. S3 for images + a database for the metadata is that it's simple. Given the low use of the database, I can't see speed being an issue. Slow backups don't seem an issue either. For this project, cost and low maintenance is important as well.

Does this seem a sensible design or could this run into problems? Is there something as simple that has advantages I'm missing?

Comment: I think you have thought out the solution and arrived at a reasonable solution.  You are essentially using the database for archival purposes, and you've considered the pros and cons.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. I think I've read the advice "don't store images in databases!!!" so often it feels like 99% of the time it's the wrong thing to do. Some kind of rule of thumb for when it's reasonable would be helpful to offset the feeling I'm doing something wrong here. To me the rule seems to be if simplicity is an important factor, you're not storing maybe more than 50GB of data and the images aren't being served too often (e.g. don't do this for a public site) then images in a database is a decent idea.

Comment: . . It depends on a lot of factors.  In general, storing large blobs in a database should not be the default option, unless you are using a database specifically designed for that purpose.  However, as with most rules regarding databases, what is true in general may not be true when you have thought through your problem and understand the consequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that pg_dump will dump your image blobs as hex, so the dump file may be huge. I would also not assume that a 1MB image will consume only 1MB in the db.

Run a test with a thousand of the same image and see if your assumptions hold water.